# Getting value from Session

Tags: php, database, session, mysqli

I have created a Login where the ID is stored in a $_SESSION['login_user'].

After authentication, the user is redirected to his home page. I wanna get the value from the session and use it in a query to retrieve all attributes from the database, corresponding with this userID. This is the code I have tried.

```
session_start();
..........
..........
..........
$uid= $_SESSION['login_user'];
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users UID ='".$uid."'");
```

It is supposed to get all the values stored in the database of table 'users', but the problem is, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Most of the time, it doesn't work. 
I would appreciate some help with this one

I have also checked whether the Session is empty or not , before going through this step.

This is the part of login when setting the Session:

```
$result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and
password='$password'");
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION['login_user']=$row['uid'];
```

Comment: `session_start();` ?

Comment: then you should add it in the question code.

Comment: Use print_r($_SESSION) before your query, to see what values are in $_SESSION.

Comment: Make sure that `$_SESSION['login_user']` isn't modified in the same page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is what it gives:

    Array ( [login_user] => )

I believe the login is not working properly, right?

Comment: Where do you specify $count?

Comment: $username and $password are assigned from the form via POST method.

Comment: I get that part @Arif_suhail, but before he updated the question, it wasnt declared

Comment: $_SESSION['login_user']=$row[0]['uid'];

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) now gives 2 which is correct

Comment: I guess so, now everything works. On one of the pages, but on the other one I think there is an error in the query. Can I ask it here, or should I post another one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using correct SQL syntax like SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE something=someval? Like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE UID ='".$uid."'");
```